# commandName error in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Please help me following error. I am learning spring MVC. I am unable to solve this problem. I have gone through many forums and websites but I could not find or solve it. However, I know this problem is because of commandName in form tag. If I remove, I am able to go to that page.

My problem is:
I have a login form in that there are many user levels.

**login.jsp**

```
<sf:form commandName="userLogin" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/userLogin" method="POST">

<sf:input path="UserName" type="text" name="UserName" class="form-control input-lg" id="focusedInput" />
<sf:errors path="UserName" cssClass="alert alert-danger"></sf:errors>

<sf:input path="password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" id="focusedInput" />
<sf:errors path="password" cssClass="alert alert-danger"></sf:errors>

<label for="sel1">Login as:<sup>*</sup></label>
  <sf:select path="userLevel" class="form-control input-lg" id="sel1" name="userLevel">
    <option value="">Select User</option>
    <option value="tenant">Tenant</option>
    <option value="manager">Manager</option>
    <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
    <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
  </sf:select>
  <sf:errors path="userLevel" cssClass="alert alert-danger"></sf:errors>

<input type="submit" value="Login"  name ="form1" class="btn btn-success btn-md">
</sf:form>
```

My controller class is

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String showHome(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("title", "Welcome to Wildwood Apartment");
    return"home";
}

@RequestMapping("/adminHome")
public String showAdmin(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("title", "Welcome to Wildwood Administrator Page");
    return"admin";
}

@RequestMapping("/managerHome")
public String showManager(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("title", "Welcome to Manager's Dashboard");
    return"manager";
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("title", "Login Page");
    return"login";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/userLogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginAction(Model model, @ModelAttribute("userLogin") @Valid Login userLogin, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){

        model.addAttribute("title", "Login Page");
        return"login";
    }
    model.addAttribute("userLogin", new Login());
    return"redirect:/adminHome";
}
```

My Bean Class
**Login.java**

```
public class Login {

@Size(min=3, max=15)
private String userName;
@Size(min=3, max=15)
private String password;
@NotBlank
private String userLevel;
//private int userid;

public Login(){}

public Login(String userName, String password, String userLevel){
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.userLevel = userLevel;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUserLevel() {
    return userLevel;
}

public void setUserLevel(String userLevel) {
    this.userLevel = userLevel;
}
}
```

My **Web.xml**

```
<display-name>WWMVC</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>WHome</display-name>
<servlet-name>WHome</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>WHome</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<resource-ref>
<description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/jagan</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

My Dispatcher Servlet
**WHome-servlet.java**

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/jagan" id="dataSource"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
</jee:jndi-lookup>

<context:component-scan base-package="controller"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/bootstrap/**" location="/bootstrap/" />
```

In my home page I have a link to login page as:

```
**<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">LOGIN</a></li>**
```

The error message which i am getting is
**HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userLogin' available as request attribute**

**Note:** I have copied and pasted most of the important codes only. Further, I am using maven and bootstrap for design. I could go to my home page but when I click on the login link I am getting the above error.

Thanks in advance.

Jagan

Comment: You get that because there is no object with that name. In your model you only add the `title`.

Comment: Hi Denium, Thanks for your comments. It works now. However, Could you please explain in a detail manner. So that, I could understand the mechanism. I mean what are the connections among model, object, commandName, and modelAttributes here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone who is in the beginning stage of learning the spring-form, then it might help. Therefore, I am commenting here.
I had an issue that I did not send the empty object to form
For example:
If I want a form for user registration:

1. I should have a User model class
2. In GetMapping for that user registration form, I should send the empty User object

   @GetMapping(/register)
   public ModelAndView registerForm(ModelAndView mv){
   mv.addObject("user", new User());
   ....
   }
3. In spring form, I should have an attribute and the name should be user
4. While processing the form, I should get the modelAttribute and process it

   public ModelAndView processRegister(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelAndView mv){
   ......
   }

Thanks
Jagan